# Merge only Missing Data

Tags: sql, ssis

I am working on an HR project that provides data to me in the form of an Excel document.

I have created a package that captures the data from the Spreadsheet and imports it into SQL. The customer then wanted to create a data connection and place the data into Pivot Tables to manipulate and run calculations on.

This brought to light a small issue that I have tried to get fixed from the source but looks like cannot be resolved on the System Side (working with an SAP backend).

What I have is information that comes into SQL from the import that is either missing the Cost Center Name or both the cost center number and the cost center name.

EXAMPLE:

```
EmpID    EmployeeName    CostCenterNo    CostCenterName
001      Bob Smith       123456          Sales
010      Adam Eve        543211          Marketing
050      Thomas Adams    121111
121      James Avery
```

I worked with HR to get the appropriate information for these employees, I have added the information to a separate table.

What I would like to do is figure out a way to insert the missing information as the data is imported into the Staging table.

Essentially completing the data.

```
EmpID    EmployeeName    CostCenterNo    CostCenterName
001      Bob Smith       123456          Sales
010      Adam Eve        543211          Marketing
050      Thomas Adams    121111          Supply Chain
121      James Avery     555316          Human Resources
```

Comment: Do not kep the CC Name in the employee table. ONLY store the CC Number there. Make a seperate table "Cost_Center" to store the ID and Name. That way, when the rename 555316 to "HR", you only have to update a single record, not all the emplyee records.

Comment: Is there any concern that the `CostCenterName` could change over time? New record comes with CostCenterNo 555316 and a CostCenterName of "Human Innovations" (they've undergone a rebranding initiative). A record also comes in with just a CostCenterNo of 555316. Your reference table is stale and applies "Human Resources" to it. Is that an issue/concern in your world? Will your users say the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Is there an issue with a basic update like

```
Update <tablename> set CostCenterNo = (SELECT CostCenterNo from <hr_sourced_table> where EmpID =x) where EmpID = x
```

In case if its needed you can add

```
Where CostcentreNo is null
```

Because even if you did not do this, it would update all data which should be correct, but for any reason if you dont need it you can update both the fields in a single query like this

```
Update <tablename> set CostCenterNo = (SELECT CostCenterNo from <hr_sourced_table> where EmpID =x),CostCenterName = (SELECT CostCenterName from <hr_sourced_table> where EmpID =x) where EmpID = x
```

Comment: In case if you are looking it as part of the import statement itself, then adding your SQL that imports may help, sorry if I misunderstood your requirement

Answer (score 1):

If your data source table and the extra mapping information are both accessible from the same place, you don't have to update anything with SSIS. Just build a view that joins the two tables and populate the pivot table from the view. You will have to decide what to do if the data source and the mapping table disagree, but that is a business rule question.

```
Select e.EMPLID, e.EmployeeName, cc.CostCenterNo, cc.CostCenterName
From Employees e
  Left Join CCMapping cc on e.emplid=cc.emplid
```

OR

```
Select e.EMPLID, e.EmployeeName, 
  coalesce(e.CostCenterNo, cc.CostCenterNo) as CostCenterNo, 
  coalesce(e.CostCenterName, cc.CostCenterName) as CostCenterName
From Employees e
  Left Join CCMapping cc on e.emplid=cc.emplid
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [lookup transformation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx) in your data flow that sources the missing data you got from HR. Then join this lookup data on a mutual field in the data coming from your sources (EmpID?). You can then add the cost center no and cost center name from the missing data table to the data flow. In a derived column transformation you can test to see if the data from the source is null and if so, use the columns that came from the missing data table to store in the destination table.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, your options are to complete the data in flight or update the data after it has landed. Which route I would chose would be dependent on the level of complexity.

### In flight

Generally speaking, this is my preference. I'd rather have all the scrubbing take place while the data is moving versus applying a series of patches afterward to shine the data.

In your Data Flow, I would have a Conditional Split to funnel the data into 2 to 3 streams: Has all data, has cost center and has nothing.

"Has all data" would route directly into a Union All

"Has cost center" would lead to a Lookup Component which would use the supplied Cost Center to lookup against the reference table to acquire the text associated to the existing value. The Lookup Component expects to find matches so if the possibility exists that a Cost Center will not exist in your reference table, you will need to handle that situation. Depending on what version of SSIS you are using will determine whether you can just use the Unmatched Output column (2008+) or whether you have to commandeer the Error Output (2005). Either way, you will need to indicate to the Lookup that failure to match should not result in a package level failure. Once you've handled this lookup and handled the no-match option, join that stream to the Union All.

"has nothing" might behave as the "has cost center" stream where you will perform some lookup on other columns to determine cost center or you might simply apply a default/known-unknown value for the missing entities. How that works will depend on the rules your business owners have supplied.

### Post processing

This keeps your data flow exactly as it is. You would simply add an Execute SQL Task after the Data Flow to polish any tarnished data. Whether I do this entirely in-line in the Execute SQL Task or create a dedicated clean up stored procedure would be based in part of the level of effort it takes to get code changed. Some places, pushing an SSIS package change is a chipshot activity. Other places, it takes an act of the SOX dieties to get a package change pushed but they were fine with proc changes.

My gut would be to push the scrubber logic into a stored procedure. Then your package wouldn't have to change every time they come up with scenarios that the original queries didn't satisfy.

You would have 2 statements in the proc, much as we performed in the In flight section. One query will update populating the Cost Center name. The other will apply cost center and name. If you need help with the specifics of the actual query, let me know and I can update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with another developer to create a solution, here is what we came up with. 
I Created an "Execute SQL Task" to run after the data flow that has this script in it.

```
MERGE [Staging].[HRIS_EEMaster] AS tgt
    USING (
    SELECT PersNo AS EmpID,
        CostCenterNo AS CCNo,
        CostCenterName AS CCName
    FROM [dbo].[MissingTermedCC]
          ) AS src ON src.EmpID = tgt.PersNo
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (
    PersNo,
    CostCenterNo,
    CostCenterSubDiv
          )
    VALUES (
        src.EmpID,
        src.CCNo,
        src.CCName
          )
    WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE
          SET tgt.CostCenterNo = CASE
          WHEN src.CCNo > '' THEN src.CCNo
          ELSE tgt.CostCenterNo
        END,
              tgt.CostCenterSubDiv = CASE
          WHEN src.CCName > '' THEN src.CCName
          ELSE tgt.CostCenterSubDiv
        END;
```

I wanted to share in case anyone else runs into a similar issue. Thanks again for all of the help everyone.

Comment: Be wary of using the [Merge](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/can-i-optimize-this-merge-statement/44069#44069) statement

Comment: I'll look and see if I can rework the merge into something a little more secure and stable. Thanks for the heads up.